# Create a column composed of several columns in a postgres data table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a column in a table in postgres for special needs, this column must consist for example of a concatenation of two another column.

for example i have

```
LAYER: 'accessory'
TYPE: 'copper'
```

I want a column (symbology) to be filled automatically during an insertion or an update by

```
SYMBOLOGY: 'accessory - copper'
```

do I need a trigger to do this or is there some other ways to avoid the trigger.

Illustration

| LAYER | TYPE | SYMBOLOGY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| accessory | copper | accessory - copper |

cordially

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html).

```
alter table things
  add column symbology text
  generated always as (layer || ' - ' || type)
  stored;
```

Or, if its only for some specific circumstances, you can create a view

```
create view thing_symbols as
select
  *,
  (layer || ' - ' || type) as symbology
from things;
```

Comment: is there a solution in 9.x versions for the generated column ?

Comment: @Kalifornium . . . In earlier versions of Postgres, you would use either a trigger or a view.